# Jsoup: Can't extract img tag

Tags: java, image, web, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the image source of a few ads but I don't understand what i'm doing wrong :(
The html tag that i want to extract looks like this:
[image]

Code:

```
Elements pageSearchImg = page2.select("a[id^=item] > div[class=placeholder] > div[class=overflow_image] > img");
        for (int m = 0; m < pageSearchImg.size(); m++) {
                String img = pageSearchImg.get(m).attr("src");
                System.out.println(img);
        }
```

I guess there might be something wrong with a tag?

Edit: if i view the page source it looks like this:

```
<a id="item_1574320" href="https://carzz.ro/dacia-logan-14-mpipreferancefab-2006originala-anunt_1574320.html" class="main_items item_cart ">

    <div class="placeholder">
                <div class="overflow_image">
                            <div id="ad_img_loader_1574320" class="ad_img_loader">
                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path fill="#d32f2f" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
                            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 25 25" to="360 25 25" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The sites is using Javascript to load the images and Jsoup does not support that. You'll have to use something else, like phantomJS to get it.

Comment: If you're planning to parse page with Jsoup, don't use your browsers inspector because it shows source already modified by Javascript. If you want to see original page source that will be available to Jsoup, use browser's 'View source' option (usually CTRL+U).

Comment: Oh ok! so it's not really working:( Thanks for answering!